# How can I make my shop’s cart clear after 30minutes in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am a web designer, and I’m working with a client whose website I’ve built on Shopify. They have a strict 12pm cut off for same-day delivery orders.

The issue is, the delivery day is selected at the cart level, and if anyone selects this and then steps away and comes back after 12pm, they’re still able to complete the checkout.

I want to be able to clear a visitors cart or refresh back to the homepage or time out the checkout or something after a 30 minute period. How would I go about doing this?

Thank you!

I’ve looked into it and I can see that I can possibly set something up using the AJAX API but I don’t really know anything about that.

Comment: Ultimately you cannot rely on user's local time(it may be fixed too), if every customer is synchronized to the same UTC time, I would create an API request to your server to get the current time and continue the logic from there. If you are not too concerned about users with malicious intent(BIG IF), then you could always get the local time and just reload() your page if a certain condition is met.

Comment: "*the delivery day is selected at the cart level, and if anyone selects this and then steps away and comes back after 12pm, they’re still able to complete the checkout*" - Why don't you just check the selected delivery date *before* completing the checkout then? If the delivery date is in the past, then throw an error notifying the customer they have to select a new delivery date instead of emptying the order?

Comment: @DarkBee but the date isn’t in the past, the problem is that same-day delivery orders need to be in midday, but if they have already gone to the checkout page and are just sitting on it, there’s nothing to time it out to stop them from checking out. so how do I get an error notification to show up?

Comment: "*there’s nothing to time it out to stop them from checking out*" - Yes there is, there is still a button they to click to actually send the order right? Here you can write the code to test if the time has passed 12PM.